# Regular expression issuse

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some troubles to write a regular expression.

I have to extract some informations from a string and identify very specific parts in it.

All parts are not mandatory.

My format is : `ORDER_filename.extension(options)` where `filename` is mandatory, and `ORDER`, `extension` and `options` are not.

For exemple, I may have :

```
100_Some file name.ext(3)
_Some other file name.ext
300_Folder name
400_Another Folder name(5)
```

I should be able to extract :

```
Order  |   Filename                 |  extension | options
----------------------------------------------------------
100    |   Some file name           |  ext       | 3
(null) |   _Some other file name    |  ext       | (null)
300    |   Folder name              |  (null)    | (null)
400    |   Another Folder name      |  (null)    | 5
```

The second line *has* the underscore in the filename.

I'm playing with [regex lib](http://regexlib.net/) a bit, but I did not succeed in extracting all my parts.

I tried:

- `^(?<order>[0-9_]+_)?(?<filename>\w+)` : but it splits the filename at space
- `^(?<order>[0-9_]+_)?(?<filename>\w+)(\.(?<ext>.+))?`: no extension is extracted. File name is still split.
- `^(?<order>[0-9_]+_)?(?<filename>\w+)(\.(?<ext>.+))?(\((?<options>.+)\))?`: neither extension nor options are extracted. File name is still split.

What is the correct expression I should use?

FYI, I'll use the C# named captures to do some job using these values.

Comment: how do you plan to distinguish between 100_file1.ext(1) <- option 1 on file1.ext and 100_file1.ext(1) <- no option on file1.ext(1) . () are valid in a file name

Comment: is `(` valid in a filename?

Comment: ( is valid. open cmd and try echo test > test.()

Comment: @Jodrell: typo in the question. The second line does not have `200_` as prefix. And yes, all expected windows file name allowed chars may be covered.

Comment: can filenames begin with numbers?

Comment: @Jodrell: maybe... but I can assume if there is an underscore after the series of digits, it it the order, not the filename. Same as the last dot that must mean this is the extension, plus the potential (single) option.

Comment: If you can enforce this regularity in your system then regular expressions will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
var re = @"(?xm)
    ^
    (?:    (?<order> \d+ ) _ )?
           (?<filename> .+? )
    (?: \. (?<ext> \w+ ) )?
    (?: \( (?<options> [^()]+ ) \) )?
    $";
```

Comment: I didn't know I can write a multiline expression. Is it related to the `(?xm)` prefix?

Comment: @SteveB, in C# at least raw `@""` strings can span multiple lines. And the `(?x)` flag makes the regex engine ignore all the white space and comments in the expression. `(?m)` makes `^` and `$` match start and end of line, instead of string.

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind,

I misunderstood the `\w` alias. This does not includes the spaces.

This expression is working as expected :

```
^(?<order>[0-9_]+_)?(?<filename>(\w|\s)+)(\.(?<ext>\w+))?(\((?<options>.+)\))?
```

**[Edit]** Unfortunately, there are some cases where this explode :

```
100_some file() name.doc(3)
```

Comment: Instead of `(\w|\s)+` you can write `[\w\s]+` (which doesn't capture anything).